# Lookup Framework Version that currently used by this application while runtime

Tags: vb.net

Good Evening Everyone,

I would like to retrieve the Framework Version while my application running on runtime.

I had tested the Environment.Version, but it returned 2.0.50727.8825, I expected to have 3.5/4.0/4.5 etc.

How could I use to retrieve these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the .NET Framework Versions 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2, the Environment.Version property returns a Version object whose string representation has the form 4.0.30319.xxxxx. For the .NET Framework 4.6, its point releases, and the .NET Framework 4.7, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000.

For the .NET Framework 4.5 and later, we do not recommend using the Version property to detect the version of the runtime; instead, you can determine the version of the common language runtime by querying the registry. For more information, see [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).